# Auth logout is not working in CakePHP 2.x

Tags: cakephp, session-cookies, browser-cache, cakephp-2.x

1. When I login from one user account session is set.Then opening the next tab on same browser and enter login url it takes me to the login page.But actually it should redirect to the "dashboard" page(in my case). It can't redirect to `loginRedirect`(dashboard) page as mentioned in my `Auth`.
2. When i logout, as per my code session,cookie and cache are deleted. but it's not redirect to `logoutRedirect` page.

My code :

**App controller**

```
public $components = array(
  'Session', 'RequestHandler', 'Email', 'Cookie',
  'Auth' => array(
    'authenticate' => array(
      'Form' => array(
        'fields' => array(
          'username' => 'email',
          'password' => 'password')
        )
      ),
      'loginRedirect' => array(
         'controller' => 'users',
         'action' => 'login'
       ),
       'logoutRedirect' => array(
         'controller' => 'users',
         'action' => 'login'
       )
     )
   );
```

**User controller**

*login action :*

```
public function login() {
  $this->layout = 'admin';    
    if ($this->Session->check('Auth.User')) {
      $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));      
    }
    if (isset($this->data['User'])) {
      if (!empty($this->data['User']['email']) && !empty($this->data['User']['password'])) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {   
          $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
        } else {
          $this->set('error', "Email or Password mismatch.");
        }
      }
    } else {
      if ($this->Auth->loggedIn()) {                
        $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
      }
    }
  }
```

*logout action :*

```
public function logout() {      
  header('pragma: no-cache'); 
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate'); 
  $this->response->disableCache();        
  $this->Session->delete('Auth.User');
  $this->Session->delete('User');
  $this->Session->destroy();
  $this->Cookie->destroy();
  return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

This code is working fine in "local server" but not working in production server.

Comment: Where is the code that redirects to your dashboard in the above snippets?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. Please review my edit.

Comment: Try removing the delete and destroy lines before the return, as Auth::logout() should handle that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `redirect` statements should have `return` in front of them so that code execution will stop there. For example:

```
return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'dashboard'));
```